# Elfsight Google Maps Plugin Version 2.1.0 : Location image input not found

Tags: plugins, google-maps

I'm using Elfsight Google Maps Plugin Version 2.1.0 in my WordPress website to create an interactive map.

1- I can’t find the image field in the description section like in the demo to upload an image to my location, and i get google building image by default for every location i create.

2- Also the pointer doesn't load i must enter "plus codes" instead of address so the location can be loaded.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this plugin [Pods – Custom Content Types and Fields](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/pods/) triggered a conflict with the Elfsight Google Maps Plugin and cause a problem with the image and address fields, uninstall it and the map will work perfectly.